# UIButton in uiimageview in UITableview cell image not changing

Tags: uitableview, uiimageview, uibutton

I have a custom uitableviewcell in that i have an imageview with a button when user clicks the button, button should show with a tick mark!

[image]

When user clicks the button it should show with a tickmark
I have a tried some thing. pls help me

```
checkBoxButton.selected=!checkBoxButton.selected;

if(checkBoxButton.selected==1){
    [checkBoxButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
}
else{
    [checkBoxButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code in your button click. This will work only if you have single 
checkbox..

```
if ([self.checkBoxButton.currentTitle isEqualToString:@"uncheck"])  {

    NSLog(@"changing to checked");
    [self.checkBoxButton setTitle:@"check" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.checkBoxButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkedbox.png"]  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}else if([self.checkBoxButton.currentTitle isEqualToString:@"check"])
{
    NSLog(@"changing to UNchecked.....");
    [self.checkBoxButton setTitle:@"uncheck" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.checkBoxButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheckedbox.png"]  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Hope this helps you...

Comment: I have multiple checkbox in mytableview. pls see the image in the link. This is not working..

Answer (score 0):

You can add properties which represent the status.

```c
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL checked;

- (void)setChecked:(BOOL)checked
{
    _checked = checked;

    if (_checked) {
        [self.checkboxButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn-checkbox-checked"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } else {
        [self.checkboxButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn-checkbox-unchecked"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

You may add target-action to your `checkBoxButton`. In the action method, set the value of `checked` property.